# How to implement progress bar as Application Indicator?

Tags: ubuntu, panel

does unity-panel support panel applets, similar to DBus-based panel applets of gnome and mate?

I know about ApplicationIndicators specification, but they are associated with square icons for me.

Is it possible to insert long progress bar between main menu and status area?

Comment: yes, there is **workrave** app which creates long rectangular (nonsquare) icons through dbus